# Docker Error: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

## Problemas al ejecutar el paso 6 del tutorial

### Error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

### Contexto del problema

El profesor en esta clase está intentando preparar un entorno de trabajo para el aprendizaje de postman, para ello se ejecuta una series de instrucciones en la lectura propuesta. estos son los pasos y lo que hice en cada uno de ellos.

### Pasos para replicar el problema

#### Tutorial  y los pasos que hice en cada una de las instrucciones del tutorial

1. Instala Docker y Docker Compose
   Lo que hice: Realice la instalación según la página oficial de docker  y esta es la versión que tengo instalada y mi entorno de trabajo:

Versión de docker y docker-compose

```
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
docker-compose version 1.29.1, build c34c88b2
```

Mi entorno de trabajo

```
OS: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 5.11.0-7614-generic 
Uptime: 3 days, 1 hour, 37 mins 
Packages: 2437 (dpkg), 45 (flatpak), 15 (snap) 
Shell: zsh 5.8
```

2. Descarga los archivos de la api haciendo click en este enlace. Estos archivos también se encuentran disponibles en la sección de archivos de la siguiente clase.
   Lo que hice: Realice la descarga del archivo  propuesto en el siguiente link:
   https://static.platzi.com/media/public/uploads/postman-course-master_ffa10d45-7eaf-4beb-b2bb-3ecb7c93eff2.zip
   una vez descargado el proyecto lo descomprimí y lo metí en una carpeta para tener más orden. La ruta del proyecto es: ~/mi_usuario/platzi-pj/curso-postman/postman-course-master
3. Ejecuta en la terminal sudo docker-compose up -d para activar los contenedores de la aplicación.
   Lo que hice: Posicionarme  en la carpeta donde se encuentra el proyecto es decir y ejecute  el comando propuesto
   para levantar los archivos.

   ```
    cd ~/platzi-pj/curso-postman/postman-course-master
    sudo docker-compose up -d
   ```
4. Entra en el contenedor ejecutando sudo docker exec -it postman-course-master_web_1 bash
   Lo que hice:  En este paso ejecute la siguiente instrucción

   sudo docker exec -it  postman-course-master_web_1 bash
5. Ejecuta cd ./project
   lo que hice: En este paso no ejecute esta entrución, ya que en el archivo: "docker-compose.yml"  se encuentra un volumen que sincroniza los  archivos de la carpeta "project"  con la carpeta "code" dentro del contenedor, entonces ejecute el paso 6  directamente. Cabe añadir que al ejecutar el comando del paso 4 el contenedor inicia en la carpeta llamada: "code" . Aquí está código del archivo docker-compose.yml  y el señalamiento que hago:

   version: '3'

   archivo: docker-compose.yml

   ```py
   version: '3'

   services:
       db:
           image: postgres
       web:
           build: .
           command: tail -F anything
           volumes:
               - ./project:/code    #  <-- los archivos de la carpeta  project están copiados en la carpeta code del contenedor
           ports:
               - '8000:8000'
           depends_on:
               - db
   ```

archivo: Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6           # Se toma la imagen de python 3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1    # Se especifica una variable de entorno
RUN mkdir /code           # Se crea la carpeta code
WORKDIR /code             # Nos posicionamos dentro de la carpeta code
COPY requirements.txt /code/   # Se copia requirements.txt del host dentro de la carpeta code del contenedor 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  # se instala los paquetes dentro del contenedor
COPY . /code/       #No entiendo lo que hace  aqui
```

6. Ejecuta migraciones de Django python manage.py migrate
   Lo que hice: Ejecute el siguiente comando   y  me arrojo el siguiente error

comando

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Error que me arroja:

```
root@b64affe3913a:/code# python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 87, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

6. Ejecuta migraciones de Django python manage.py migrate
   Lo que hice: Ejcute el siguiente comando   y  me arrojo el siguiente error

comando

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Error que me arroja:

```
root@b64affe3913a:/code# python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 87, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

NOta importante al ejecutar  la siguiente instrucción

```
sudo docker-compose ps
```

muestra lo siguiente:

```
postman-course-master_db_1    docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Exit 1                                           
postman-course-master_web_1   tail -F anything                Up       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp,:::8000->8000/tcp
```

y si se ejecuta:

```
sudo docker ps
```

Muestra  que solo hay un servicio corriendo

```
postman-course-master_web   "tail -F anything"   25 seconds ago   Up 20 seconds   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   postman-course-master_web_1
```

Comment: Prueba ejecutando `docker-compose up ` sin el `-d` para si en el trazo te muestra por qué se cae el servicio `db`

Comment: Me recomienda dos cosas la primera crear una contraseña y la segundo   que puedo permitir cualquier conexión. pero esto último me indica que es algo peligroso. Entonces en mi archivo   docker-compose.yml agregue una variable de entorno indicando  el password... si logro hacer que funcione publico una solución me guíe de estos dos links muchas gracias
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750715/could-not-translate-host-name-db-to-address-using-postgres-docker-compose-and

Answer (score 1):

respuesta a la ejecución del docker anterior es la siguiente,

Contexto de la solución: Realmente la primera configuración estaba mal y hubo una actualización del código, así que la solución es la siguiente

1. Instala Docker y Docker compose, en mi caso uso linux específicamente pop-os que es una version basada en ubuntu 20.04 y utilice los siguientes links de referencia:

[instalar docker en linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)
[instalar docke-compose en linux](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

1. Descargue el proyecto del siguiente enlace:
   [Proyecto actulizado](https://github.com/walis85300/postman-course)
2. Descomprimí el proyecto en mi carpeta home de linux y luego abrí una terminal y me posicione dentro de la carpeta del proyecto:

   cd ~/postman-course-master
3. Levente los servicios junto con los contenedores de cada servicio ejecutando:

   sudo docker-compose up -d
4. Entre en el contenedor del servicio web:

   sudo docker exec -it postman-course-master_web_1 bash
5. Una vez dentro del contenedor me posicione en el carpeta project:

   cd ./project
6. Luego ejecute las migraciones de Django ejecutando:

   python manage.py migrate
7. Dentro del mismo  contenedor ejecute  la siguiente instrucción para crear al superusuario.

   source admin_info.sh
8. como lo indica el tutorial  realize la carga los datos iniciales con:

`
python manage.py loaddata courses/fixtures/initial_data.json

Ejecuta exit para salir del contenedor.
Reinicia la aplicación con sudo docker-compose stop y nuevamente sudo docker-compose up -d.
Comprueba que tu servidor se encuentre disponible entrando a la siguiente url http://localhost:8000/api/